# Passing variables into verbatim string literal for JSON request body

Tags: c#, json

Fairly new to C# and I'm trying to build a clean-ish multi line string using a verbatim string literal, but also trying to pass in variables to it.

Says it is not formatted correctly, so seeing what I am doing wrong here, as this format is close to what I've seen in other SO questions.

```
  var bodyJson =string.Format(@"{
                                  ""ConsultingProject@odata.bind"": ""/consultingprojectses({0})"",
                                  ""buyer_product_id@odata.bind"": ""products(f4b6b505-99df-e711-8108-c4346bdc3201)"",
                                  ""BuyerLookupId@odata.bind"": ""/contacts({1})"",
                                  ""new_buyer_account_id@odata.bind"": ""/accounts({2})""
                                }", projectRecord.consultingprojectsid, contact, projectRecord.account_value);
```

Or preferably this:

```
  var bodyJson =string.Format(@"{
                                  'ConsultingProject@odata.bind': '/consultingprojectses({0})',
                                  'buyer_product_id@odata.bind': 'products(f4b6b505-99df-e711-8108-c4346bdc3201)',
                                  'BuyerLookupId@odata.bind': '/contacts({1})',
                                  'tnew_buyer_account_id@odata.bind': '/accounts({2})'
                                }", projectRecord.consultingprojectsid, contact, projectRecord.account_value);
```

Comment: JSON is serialized data from a model or object; rather than concocting a fancy string use a serializer

Comment: You have to escape the `{` and `}`. [How to escape braces (curly brackets) in a format string in .NET](//stackoverflow.com/a/91375)

Comment: Please don't do this.  Create an object and use a serializer!

Comment: You may want to consider using `JObject` to create the necessary structure and values rather than trying to escape and all that; for instance, technically you have invalid JSON because strings must use double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: Why not try replace by placing some place holder like `bodyJson.Replace("{0}","myvalue")`

Comment: If I remember correctly: `'` is not valid in json to denote strings - only `"` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an object and use a serializer to construct your Json:

```
var obj = new
            {
                Key1 = "value1",
                Key2 = "value2"
            };

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```